# Output of subprocess gets appended to file before time

Tags: python, time, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I'm using subprocess to output std output and std error to their respective files. When I try to output time to both files before the respective messages, it is being written at the end.

Below is the code

```
import time
from subprocess import call

datetime_log = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
with open("stdout.txt","ab") as stdout_file, open("stderr.txt","ab") as stderr_file:
    stdout_file.write(datetime_log + '\n'); stderr_file.write(datetime_log + '\n')
    call(['ls'], stdout = stdout_file, stderr = stderr_file)
```

The output of stdout.txt is:

```
pyshell1.py
pyshell2.py
stderr.txt
stdout.txt
2019-03-11 17:59:48
pyshell1.py
pyshell2.py
stderr.txt
stdout.txt
2019-03-11 18:06:17
```

How do I print the time **before** the output of `ls` subprocess command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the buffer:

```
stdout_file.write(datetime_log + '\n')
stderr_file.write(datetime_log + '\n')
stdout_file.flush()
stderr_file.flush()
call(['ls'], stdout=stdout_file, stderr=stderr_file)
```

Comment: You might also need to call [`fsync`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsync) after flushing the buffers. Your data might get stuck in the file system buffer after being flushed from the FILE* stream buffer.